# Nodes and Stacks adding error

Tags: stack, nodes

I'm trying to create a code for a card game in Java, and I have encountered a problem. 
My deck is a `Stack<Character>` and a static for my class named `Players` and my 'hand' is a private `Node<Character>`. 
I've created a method that pops a card from my deck and adds it to my hand. 
It's code:

```
public void takeCard() {
    char a = Players.deck.pop();
    Node<Character> hand = new Node<Character>(this.hand);
    while(hand.getNext()!=null) {
        hand = hand.getNext();
    }
    Node<Character> next = new Node<Character>(a, null);
    hand.setNext(next);

    this.hand = hand;
}
```

And it doesn't work and tells me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Players.takeCard(Players.java:56)
at Game.main(Game.java:31)
```

(Game is where my main function is)

Any idea how I should write the function?

Answer (score 0):

The only possible place where this code can throw a `NullPointerException` with that stack trace is in

```
char a = Players.deck.pop();
```

if `Players.deck` is `null`. It looks like you're not initialising your deck.

Add

```
assert(Players.deck!=null);
```

at the beginning of the method, and see if it burps.

Comment: @MaximAkristiniy right, but that won't throw a NPE. That will just pass `null` to the `Node` constructor. And it can't be that that constructor is throwing the exception on receiving `null`, because otherwise it would show up in the stack trace.

Comment: The thing is that i initialized the deck by using 'push()' for stacks. I know that the deck isn't empty.
(edit):In addition, what does 'assert' does? Is it supposed to print me something in the case of an error?

Comment: @JonathanGold you need to say which is line 56 of `Players.java`, where you're getting the exception.

Comment: @JonathanGold yes, an assertion will do nothing if it evaluates to `true`, and stop with an `AssertionError` if it's `false`.

Comment: line 56 in my class Players.java is:
char a = Players.deck.pop();
Which I think that means the variable 'deck' is empty.

Comment: @JonathanGold It means it's `null`! If it were empty, you might get an error (even a `NullPointerException`) from the `pop()` method, but this would then have shown up in your stack trace.